# Convert file input from a form to pdf and store in a MySQL database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf-generation, multipartform-data, file-conversion

I have a requirement to store uploaded files in a mysql database. Currently, I'm storing them in a blob format but I'm not converting the files before I store them in the database. I would like to convert the file to pdf format before I store them.

This is the form I'm using:

```
<form:form id="add__document" class="form-horizontal form-label-left"   
        action="saveDoc?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" 
        method="POST" modelAttribute="newDoc" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Expiry Date: </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">        
        <form:input id="expiryDate" path="expiryDate" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Upload File: </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">       
    <form:input class="btn" type="file" path="document" name="document"/>    
    </div>            
</div>

<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form:form>
```

And this is my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/saveDoc"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addNewDocument(@ModelAttribute NewDoc newdoc, HttpServletRequest request,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception  {    

newdoc.setFile(newdoc.getDocument().getBytes());
newdoc.setContentType(newdoc.getDocument.getContentType());

documentsDAO.addDocument(newdoc);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/DocumentsPage");

}
```

The addDocument method will insert the data into the MySQL table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "converting"? Converting non-PDF files to PDF?

Comment: Yes. I want to convert image files and word documents into pdf and then store them in the database.

Comment: Then you should pick an appropriate framework for such tasks. iText, POI etc.

Comment: I was working with iText, but wanted to know if there is any other alternative solution.